# How does mySQL handle dynamic value within ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

It stumbled upon me while I was reading the query in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777306/).

Take the following query for example (ignore the non-practical use of the ordering):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM Members 
ORDER BY (TIMESTAMPDIFF(FRAC_SECOND, DateCreated , SYSDATE()))
```

Say "Members" table has a huge row count (or the query is complex enough for it to be executed over at least dozen of milliseconds). How does mySQL or other mainstream DB engines evaluate the "`SYSDATE()`" in the "`ORDER BY`"?

Say the query takes half a second, the microsecond (`FRAC_SECOND`) of "SYSDATE" changes 1000 X 1000 X 0.5 = 500 000 times.

My questions are:

1. Does the "SYSDATE" get fixed on the
   start of the query execution or it
   gets evaluated and changes as the
   execution progresses?
2. If it's the latter, can I assume the ordering might be jumbled?

**UPDATE:**
My original post uses `NOW` as an example of dynamic value, it's `SYSDATE` now

Comment: It makes sense that when used in the ORDER BY, SYSDATE is only evaluated once otherwise you'd have a moving target as SYSDATE is deterministic.  Because of uncertainty about the behavior, it's best practiced to set the date value to a variable prior to use in the query.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: According to Heavy Btyes' post, SYSDATE is evaluated during execution, not just once. Do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NOW() returns a constant time that
>   indicates the time at which the
>   statement began to execute. (Within a
>   stored function or trigger, NOW()
>   returns the time at which the function
>   or triggering statement began to
>   execute.) This differs from the
>   behavior for SYSDATE(), which returns
>   the exact time at which it executes as
>   of MySQL 5.0.12.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

In other words, it is executed only once when the statement is executed.
However, if you want to obtain the time at each execution you should use SYSDATE

> As of MySQL 5.0.12, SYSDATE()  returns
>   the time at which it executes. This
>   differs from the behavior for NOW(),
>   which returns a constant time that
>   indicates the time at which the
>   statement began to execute. (Within a
>   stored function or trigger, NOW()
>   returns the time at which the function
>   or triggering statement began to
>   execute.)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate

**Update:**
Well, from what I know `Order by` will be executed or better said "used" only once. Since the value of `TIMESTAMPDIFF(FRAC_SECOND, DateCreated , SYSDATE())` will be different every time you execute the `SELECT` statement. So, I think (once again I think) `ORDER BY` will consider either the first evaluated value of the timestampdiff or the last one. Anyway, I think by executing this - you will get a random order every time. Maybe there are better experts than me here who can answer better.

Comment: Ah I see, ok so let me modify the question a bit. That's great info by the way. +1

Comment: @Heavy Bytes: I've modified my post with a new sub-question. Care to give it another shot? :)

Comment: Well, from what I know Order by will be executed or better said "used" only once. 
Since the value of TIMESTAMPDIFF(FRAC_SECOND, DateCreated , SYSDATE()) will be different every time you execute the SELECT statement. So, I think (once again I think) ORDER BY will consider either the first evaluated value of the timestampdiff or the last one.
Anyway, I think by executing this - you will get a random order every time. Maybe there are better experts than me here who can answer better.

Comment: Hope you don't mind I appended your above comment to your answer, I think it looks more complete for readers :P Too bad I can't upvote you twice :P

Comment: Sure, are you satisfied with the answer?
I guess the best way to find out how it works is to actually test it :)

Comment: @Heavy Bytes: I appreciate your effort for sure, I'm still waiting for the experts/gurus (as you said) to come along. I might do some testing myself though :)