# MySql sorting values from highest to lowest except zero with group by

Tags: mysql, sorting

Here is my query

```
SELECT name, price, MIN(price) AS minprice 
FROM c, cp 
WHERE c.id = cp.id 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY minprice = 0, minprice ASC
```

But the error show me 'Reference minprice not supported (reference to group function)'.

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

I am facing another problem, hope your expert can give me idea how to solve it

For Example:

```
id  name         price
 1     apple          0
 1     green apple    20
 2     orange         10
 3     strawberry     0
```

As the data result above the minprice of the group 1 is 0 But I don't want the min price take zero, but this is incorrenct if I give condition minprice > 0 cause

I wanna my result become like this

```
2  orange         10 
1  green apple    20
3  strawberry      0
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777306/mysql-error-1247-reference-karma-not-supported-reference-to-group-functio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532788/reference-not-supported-on-group-function

Comment: Wow. Can you please give us some information about table structure, some example rows, and what you want to see in the output? Because if you can clean up the minprice problem (a condition in the ORDER BY clause), you're going to run in to more trouble with an unqualified "id" in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use reference like minprice etc.. Instead of, use MIN(price) direct.

Comment: hi, can I ask you one more question? Currently, I am facing this problem

For Example:
group name         price
1     apple          0
1     green apple    20
2     orange         10
3     strawberry      0

As the data result above the minprice of the group 1 is 0 But I don't want the min price take zero, but this is incorrenct if I give condition minprice > 0 cause

I wanna my result become like this

2  orange         10 
1  green apple    20
3  strawberry      0

Is it possible?

Comment: Please format your comment for good readability or post a different question.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting this non formatted query but I think you need 'having' clause in your query.
`having MIN(price) > 0` or as per your need.

Comment: sorry about the my untidy post. I will post it to another question for this case.